# Mozilla Extension: Multiple States between multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am creating a mozilla extension that converts the content of a webpage on click of the "convert button"(Label: Convert) in other language
and its label gets converted to English so that on click of that button(Label: English) the content gets converted into original form

[image]

[image]

I tried to set attribute "changedcontent" with each tab so that on event focus ,focussed tab reads its "changedcontent" attribute and set the label on button ("Convert" or "English")

problem arises where i need to switch between multiple tabs, plugin in the different tab should maintain different state depending on whether it is displaying changed content(should display button label: English)
or it is in its original form(should display button label: "Convert")

so when i click refresh button or click other link in the webpage. The label of the button which is "English" with converted content on the page should gets changed to "Convert"
 so for this i have handled page unload event to track page refresh or link click, but since webpage may contain multiple frames/iframes this event is getting called multiple times. 
If in the meantime i switch the tab, label of other tab gets converted from "English" to "Convert"

code of the unload event is:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', unloadingDocument, true);
function unloadingDocument()
{

    var currentTab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
    currentTab.setAttribute("changedcontent" , "false");//set the transliterated attribute back to false
    var convertButton = document.getElementById("convert_button");
    convertButton.setAttribute("label","Convert");
}
```

Please suggest how can i solve this problem and maintain different states of mozilla plugin between multiple tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Session Store API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Session_store_API) to have independent state between tabs.

-- EDIT:

So if you already have a way to know if a specific tab is "Translated or not", if you want the button to change to have the correct state when another tab is selected, you might want to check for the tabSelect event: [Detecting tab selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection)
In this event you check your tab attribute to check if you have to change or not the label/behaviour of your button.

-- Edit 2 :

If when you click the "Convert" button you do your processing, and you set the attribute `changedcontent` of that tab to `true`. Then you have a `load/unload listener` to check for the refresh, to change the state back to `false`. Then if you change tabs, you would have the `tabSelect` event to change the button whenever you change tabs.

If you add this listener when you change `changedcontent` to `true`. Then when the event `beforeunload` is first called, you check if `changedcontent` is `true`, you change it to `false` and remove the listener.

Comment: this is however already been done through attaching attribute with each tab, but how to handle it when refresh is pressed or other inner link is clicked or if i switch between tabs when refresh is pressed as mentioned in question

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That too is not going to work in my scenario.. i want to capture event when page is refreshed or when inner link is clicked and that too only once not for each frame inside that webpage, that happens in case of load or unload event

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work. If when you click the "Convert" button you do your processing, and you set the attribute  changedcontent of that tab to true. Then you have a load/unload listener to check for the refresh, to change the state back to false. Then if you change tabs, you would have the tabSelect event to change the button whenever you change tabs. Am i missing something?

Comment: see when u press refresh the page start gets loading and event unload gets called multiple times may be if multiple frames are present on that page, where i am changing the attribute(changedcontent) to false so if during this process tabs are switched then the var currentTab = gBrowser.selectedTab; will give other tab as selected tab and change its attribute'changedcontent' to false which is not desired

Comment: So your problem might be the event you are listening to. You might want to try a different event, like the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload)

Comment: exactly.. and that event must get called only once immediately only when page is refreshed or inner link is clicked

Comment: So were you able to do it this way?

Comment: No! because i want to set that attribute to false for current tab    currentTab.setAttribute("changedcontent" , "false"); on which event is fired and beforeunload event is called multiple times for each frame/iframe on that page

Comment: If you add this listener when you change the "changedcontent" to "true". Then when the event beforeunload is first called, you check if changedcontent is "true", you change it to false and remove the listener. Isn't this enough for you?

Comment: Thanks Filipe, adding the listener when attribute is set to true and removing it when changed to false has solved the problem upto certain extent.you can modify the answer and include your last comment in it so that i can accept your answer